# jxBrowser in JavaFx - Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get native window handle

Tags: java, javafx, java-11, jxbrowser, openjfx

I just tried to add a the jxBrowser to my jfx application,

this is  my object:

```
class fxBrowserPane extends MyPane{

private Button _go;
private TextField _addr;
private HBox _bar;
private BorderPane _bp;

private BrowserView _nodevW;
private  Browser _browser;
private String url;

public fxBrowserPane(JSONObject json){
    super(json);
    url =  jsonobj.getString("url"); //url is https://www.google.com
    node = new AnchorPane();
    
    _bp = new BorderPane();
    _bar = new HBox(); //pannello con la barra degli indirizzi
    _go = new Button();
    _go.setText("GO");
    _addr = new TextField();
    _bar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    _addr.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    _bar.getChildren().addAll(_addr,_go);
    HBox.setHgrow(_addr, Priority.ALWAYS);
    _bar.setPadding(new Insets(1));
    _bar.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);
    _bp.setTop(_bar);    
}

//this is my start method:

public int start(){
   Engine engine = Engine.newInstance(
            EngineOptions.newBuilder(HARDWARE_ACCELERATED).enableIncognito().build());
    _browser = engine.newBrowser();
    _browser.navigation().loadUrl(url);
    _nodevW = BrowserView.newInstance(_browser);

    if (url != null) {
        _addr.setText(url);
        (_browser).navigation().loadUrl(url);
        System.err.println("load URL:"+url);
    }
    
    ((AnchorPane)node).getChildren().addAll(_bp);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(_bp, 0.0);
    _bp.setCenter(_nodevW);
    
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And this is the odd Exception I get:

```
xception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get native window handle
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.Platform.lambda$nativeHandle$0(Platform.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.Platform.nativeHandle(Platform.java:131)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget.attach(WindowedWidget.java:218)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget.show(WindowedWidget.java:177)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget.setWindow(WindowedWidget.java:319)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget.access$1500(WindowedWidget.java:46)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget$SceneChangeListener.setScene(WindowedWidget.java:496)
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.view.javafx.internal.WindowedWidget$SceneChangeListener.lambda$changed$0(WindowedWidget.java:478)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

These are my vmargs:

```
-classpath "D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-7.13.jar;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-win32-7.13.jar;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-win64-7.13.jar;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-mac-7.13.jar;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-linux64-7.13.jar;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\projectBrowser\lib\fxBrowser\lib\jxbrowser-linux64-arm-7.13.jar" -Djava.security.auth.login.config=resources/com/sitti/mfz/login/login.config --module-path "D:\Strumenti_di_sviluppo\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"  --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum=ALL-UNNAMED
```

```
public abstract class MyPane{
   protected string type;
   protected JSONObject conf;

   MyPane(JSONObject jobj){
     this.type = jobj.getString("type");
      this.conf = jobj;
}

 abstract int start();

}
```

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/troubleshooting.html#illegalaccessexception-in-openjfx) they recommend to add more `--add.exports`:

> In order to run JxBrowser under OpenJFX the following VM parameters must be applied at runtime:

```
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.stage=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.traversal=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Although I must add that this did not solve it for me.